# Proving or disproving matrix $A+B$ is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, examples-counterexamples

> Given $A, B \in M_n (\Bbb F)$, where $A$ is $k$-nilpotent and $B$ is invertible, is $A+B$ also invertible?

---

I was having trouble on how to prove this, and then I thought maybe this statement is incorrect, but couldn't find a counter example. Perhaps someone can assist?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is not true in general. Take
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix} 0  &1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix},
\quad
B= \begin{pmatrix} 0  &-1 \\ 1& 0 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
However, $I+A$ is always invertible for nilpotent $A$. The same holds for $A+B$ with invertible $B$ if $A$ and $B$ commute:
If $A$ and $B$ commute, then $A$ and $B^{-1}$ commute, which implies that $B^{-1}A$ is nilpotent, moreover $I-(-B^{-1}A)$ is invertible with
$$
(I-(-B^{-1}A))^{-1} = \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} (-B^{-1}A)^{i}
$$
which implies
$$
(A+B)^{-1} = B^{-1}(I+B^{-1}A)^{-1}.
$$

Comment: And now you have a second proof that $AB \neq BA$ for your specific example! ;)  Small nitpick: if we're assuming $A$ is $k$-nilpotent, then the sum in your formula needs only to run from $i = 0$ to $i = k - 1$.

Comment: @MichaelJoyce: sure, but it's not wrong to go up to $n$...

Comment: @anderstood of course, but then you need to know/prove $k\le n$. Changed it to $k-1$ to be on the 'safe' side.

Comment: @anderstood: You're absolutely right.  My nitpick was a (very, very minor) aesthetic one, not a critique of the actual content.

Answer (score 9):

A counterexample for $n=2$ by taking

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$$
and 
$$B=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\1&1\end{pmatrix}$$

Answer (score 5):

Hint:  Consider the case $k = 2$ with $A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$.  Can you find a matrix $B$ with linearly independent columns such that the columns of $A + B$ become linearly dependent?